# I want to use Microsoft.Office.InterOp.Excel to convert a .csv file to .xlsx c# .net 6

Tags: c#, excel, package

Hope all you are well, write here to ask for your help , I want to use `Microsft.Office.Interop.Excel` to generate a `.xlsx` file from a CSV. However the program generates the following Exception:

> "System.IO.FileNotFoundException
> HResult=0x80070002
> Mensaje = Could not load file or assembly 'office, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'. El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado.
> Origen = XLSXInterOp
> Seguimiento de la pila:
> en XLSXInterOp.ConverterX.Conver() en C:\path\XLSXInterOp\Program.cs: línea 39
> en XLSXInterOp.Program.Main(String[] args) en C: \path\XLSXInterOp\Program.cs: línea 10
> "

I tried to use the command prompt gcutil to add the reference , but does not work.

Advice to know how I can fix this problem to generate a xlsx file

```
        public  void ConverterF() 
        {
            var excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        //Rename the file .csv to .xls(Even if u r going to create the workbook in .xlsx extension)
        string path =@"C:\Escritorio\ExcelFile.csv";
        string xlsFile;
       xlsFile = Path.ChangeExtension(path, ".xls");

        //Create the workbook
        var workbook = excelApp.Workbooks;

            workbook.OpenText("ExcelFile.Csv.xls",
                              DataType: Microsoft.Office.
                Interop.Excel.XlTextParsingType.xlDelimited,
                              ConsecutiveDelimiter: true,
                             Comma: true);

            //Convert To excel
            workbook[1].SaveAs("NewTest.xlsx",     Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault);

            workbook.Close();


        }
```

Comment: you need to install interop from your office install. Missing file in your case is `office.dll`

Comment: I am sure you can find a nuget package which will do this much more efficiently

Comment: Yes, I found NPOI which is Open Source, I would like to implement the code in a SSIS task script, thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is normally caused by one of two things:

- Office/Excel is not installed on the machine you are trying to run this on
- This program does not have permission on the directory in which the MS Office dll(s) live

As an alternative solution, I highly recommend checking out [EPPlus](https://www.epplussoftware.com/) - it gives you some nice functionality for creating or manipulating Excel documents without the single-threadedness of interop or its dependency on having Excel actually installed.

Comment: Thanks Ii could do it using NPOI.dll, which is Open Source, and works fine. The disadvantage about EPPlus is it has a cost, if I am incorrect feel free to tell me, thanks.

Comment: @DianaTorrontegui - it is free for non-commercial use.